# Creating a button cooldown

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I was wondering how would I create a cooldown to prevent people from spamming the button. I tried this.

```
timer1.Interval = 60000; // time is milliseconds lol
timer1.Start();
```

But every time, 1 minute is over, it keeps pressing it by itself. I wanna make it so it will just stop after the cooldown is over. But I'm more interested in the cooldown.

I am using C# windows forms

Comment: show us your code

Comment: Explain what you mean by "cooldown", please

Comment: what I mean by cooldown is to prevent the user from pressing the same action twice and having to wait a time limit

Answer (score 3):

You could also do it with a async Task.

```
private bool inCooldown = false;
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (inCooldown)
        return;

    inCooldown = true;
    // your button click code
    await Task.Delay(6000);
    inCooldown = false;
}
```

You could also use a new thread, but it depends on system resources.

```
private bool inCooldown = false;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (inCooldown)
        return;

    inCooldown = true;
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(6000);
        inCooldown = false;
    });
    // your button click code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit confusing, but if I understood correctly, using a `Stopwatch` may be a simpler and resource economic approach:

```
private readonly Stopwatch _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
private const int _myCoolDown = 60000;

private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!_stopwatch.IsRunning || _stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > _myCoolDown) {
        _stopwatch.Start();
        _stopwatch.Reset();
        // do button click work here
    }
}
```

You can call Start() on your constructor or elsewhere, I used it on button click to start after the first click just as an example.

More info on Stopwatch class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-5.0

Comment: Im using windows forms with timer

Comment: This works with winforms too, actually I strongly recommend using a `Stopwatch` instead of a `Timer` because a `Timer` would use more system resources with threading.

Comment: Also, the behavior you are looking for is better achieved by a `Stopwatch` because a `Timer`, as you experienced, will be continuously firing if you don't stop it.
A `Stopwatch` on the other hand, will only do something when the button is in fact clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my question with a simple script:

```
timer1.Interval = 60000; // here time in milliseconds  // 1 minute = 60000 milliseconds
timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
timer1.Start();
button4.Enabled = false;
```

and

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Stop();
    button4.Enabled= true;
}
```